# how to retrieve last result from database when it is inserted

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps, gps

I want to know how to make some sort of event in javascript that will be triggered ever time when new data is inserted?

I need this so I can use live tracking in google maps.

For example this is the code that I have found on geolocation page:

```
function scrollMap(position) 
{
// Scrolls the map so that it is centered at (position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude).
}
// Request repeated updates.
var watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(scrollMap);

 function buttonClickHandler() 
 {
 // Cancel the updates when the user clicks a button. 
 //I want to put my code in here so for example when I click button live tracking starts.

   navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchId);
 }
```

This is my code that I am using to retrieve array of the data:

```
function initialize() {
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 180);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
      myOptions);
  var flightPlanCoordinates = [<?php echo implode(',', $coordinates) ?>];
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
}
```

How can I make my code to work and get one last result every time it is inserted in the database? And show it on the map in the google code that is provided  at the begining of my question.

Database is mysql it has ID,Latitude and Longitude.

EDIT:

This is my PHP code that fetches all data from database and put them in the array for google maps:

```
$coordinates  = array();
$result = dbMySql::Exec('SELECT Latitude,Longitude FROM data');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
   $coordinates[] = 'new google.maps.LatLng(' . $row['Latitude'] . ', ' . $row['Longitude'] . ')';
```

Comment: Why don't you  put pointers in your code `//This is where I'd like to set an event handler` and `//This is where I'd like to fire the event`

Comment: @JuanMendes okay I'll do this now

Comment: But where is the database call, or where do you want it?

Comment: So are you are trying to track a plane in flight and update the map with the current position whenever it changes?

Comment: @vari no I am tracking car, my data are inside the php code that fetches in this example all data from database

Comment: I have put the php code in the question

Comment: So maybe I can use trigger in mysql? Maybe I can get last result from query? And how to connect my result which will be one record in the live tracking

Comment: Is the page going to update the database? If so, the code that makes the Ajax request will fire an event. If you want to be notified whenever the database is edited (from anywhere), that's waaaaaaayyy harder. You would need triggers and a WebSocket server that listens for that trigger. Too much to describe here...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to poll your server. Ask for entries created within the last X minutes and add the new entries.

Comment: @denonth: What do you mean there is no update to the database? Your question is about being notified when something is inserted to the database.

Comment: Code is inserted from c# every 5 sec. For example I start live tracking and when first insert appears I start showing live